# Unable to Block Form Submission When Validation Fails

Tags: jquery, forms

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5g1bp35e/)

```
<form method="post" action="forms/post.asp" onsubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <button type="submit" onclick="validate();">Button</button>
</form>
```

I've made it work in other pages but it simply won't work on anything now. Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function validate() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions called from event attributes need to be in scope of the `window` object. To fix your problem move the function outside jQuery's `document.ready` handler:

```
function validate() {
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // jquery code here...
});
```

Alternatively, remove the outdated event attributes entirely and use unobtrusive JS to attach your events. As you're already using jQuery, here's how to do that:

```
<form method="post" action="forms/post.asp">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        var valid = true;

        // validate your form here...

        if (!valid)
            e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was possible to use actual jquery to do the job neatly but din't know how.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but do you know how I can make this work in IE? I've been forced to develop something for IE9 and it just won't work. Thanks

Comment: Both of the above should work fine in IE9. It may be worth starting a new question with the error - should you have one